# push_back to a vector while other threads try to read - race condition?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, race-condition

I have a function that adds elements to a `std::vector` and that runs in a given thread:

```
// called in one thread    
void foo(std::vector<int>& v) {
  // use v.push_back()
}
```

Is it safe to have other threads using range-based `for` loops trying to read from `v`?

```
// called in other threads
void g(std::vector<int>& v) {
  for(const auto& elem:v) {
    // read only
  }
}
```

It seems to me this could be a race condition because the size of `v` can change while other threads try to read it. Is this indeed unsafe code?

Comment: Yes, definitely unsafe, especially if the vector reallocates very bad things will happen

Comment: _"Is this indeed unsafe code?"_ Yes.

Comment: It's a race condition because one thread is modifying the data while one or more other threads are reading it. Full stop. No need to think about what might be happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic Race condition. You need a lock (like a `std::mutex`) to protect the `vector` against concurrent access.